# Count Values in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, row

I'm new here and into programming ... I'm doing a small project and have a question.

How can I count the number of entries in a single row / column?
As you can see in the photo, Female --> 1; female, female --> 2 etc.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a portion of the data itself in the question. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for how.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Using [pandas.Series.str.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df_cf["count"] = df_cf["borrower_genders"].str.count("female")
```

Comment: If this solves your problem consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer to help others in the future find the help they need.